# Sticky XUL toolbar button

Tags: firefox, xul

As I can see, addon-bar in FireFox 4 is a toolbar and close icon is a button. And despite the fact that toolbar is customizable (customizable="true") it is impossible to remove that button or even move it to another place.

How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you overlay the element directly on to the toolbar (rather than the toolbarpalette, which is what you normally do) then you won't be able to move it unless you set the removable="true" attribute on the element.

Comment: You were right. Now I need to figure out how to stick these no-nremoveable buttons to certain positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the button (I haven't tried moving it around).
I used Dom Inspector addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/

Notice that close button is gone on the screenshot.

[image]

I did this manually through Dom Inspector - added that attribute hidden = true. Your button id is addonbar-closebutton so from chrome (chrome overlay) you should be able to do something like: document.getElementById('addonbar-closebutton').hidden = true. This is off the top of my head so maybe it isn't the most accurate but should be simple as that.

If you want to move it I suppose you can try reordering children, or mess with styling, that toolbarspring I think is keeping it on the left and the rest of it on the right.

Comment: Well, I don't want to remove that button. The thing is that user can not remove it when he chooses "customize" from context menu. And I want to repeat the same effect on my own toolbar.